# Get appId with AGConnectServicesConfig failed

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect, huawei-map-kit

I have some doubts about this message in the logcat ：

`E/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: Get appId with AGConnectServicesConfig failed`

If this error or message could give problems in the future since it is displayed when viewing the Maps Kit Map?
I have already tried the following:

1. No apply plugin of agconnect in build.grade
2. Manually add

```
<meta-data 
   android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.appid" 
   <!-- Replace xxx with the actual app ID, which can be obtained on the App information page. --> --> 
   android:value="appid=xxx"> 
</meta-data>
<!-- Replace xxx with the actual payment ID, which can be obtained from the app's IAP information. --> -->
<meta-data
   android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.cpid"
   android:value="cpid=xxx">
</meta-data>
```

But the message keeps popping up, is there anything else to consider? Would this message affect in some future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank for for providing the information regarding this issue.
This `E/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: Get appId with AGConnectServicesConfig failed` message is printed when the HMS framework cannot get the AppID from AppGallery, if your App hasn't been uploaded onto the AppGallery, it is normal to show this message.
The framework will then get the AppID from `agconnect-services.json` file or manifest.xml, and the information is used by framework itself, will not influence the usage of Map Kit.